# Colored element with black connections in circuitikz

Tags: color, circuitikz

I want to draw a colored element (say a blue capacitor) but I want to keep the color of its connections (end points) as  black dots.  The code being used is given below which results in end points being blue whereas I want them black. How can it be done in circuitikz? I would appreciate your help as I have been looking all over but could not find any help on this.

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} 
  \draw(0,0) to [C,l_=$C$,*-*,color=blue](0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm... your MWE does not compile...

Comment: @Tash was the answer suitable

Comment: Thanks js bibra. I have a big document which has many circuits already made. So I was looking for something where I don't have to change anything in the document but I am ok to modify the preamble. You solution is good if I am writing a new document. Thanks for you the help. I will probably go with one of the two solutions Rmano or Marijn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, well --- I have to admit that the `circuitikz` management of color is quite buggy (and I just noticed a leakage in the manual, that I'll try to correct), but you can define a kind of "always black" poles like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
% this is what the OP asked for
% notice that the manual is buggy
% always black pole styles
\tikzset{bcirc/.style={circ, color=black}}
\ctikzset{b-b/.style = {bipole nodes={bcirc}{bcirc}}} 
% for fun
\tikzset{gcirc/.style={circ, color=green}, 
        rsquare/.style={osquarepole, fill=yellow,
        % you must use the circuitikz explicitly here
        circuitikz/color=blue}}
\ctikzset{c-c/.style = {bipole nodes={gcirc}{rsquare}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
    \draw[](0,0) to [C,l_=$C$, color=blue, b-b] ++ (0,2);
    \draw[color=blue](2,0) to [C,l_=$C$, b-b] ++ (0,2);
    % for fun
    \draw[](4,0) to [C,l_=$C$, color=red, c-c] ++ (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

If what you need is to supersede the poles in an already made circuit, you can just change the definition of the standard poles:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
% this is what the OP asked for
% notice that the manual is buggy
% always black pole styles
\tikzset{bcirc/.style={circ, color=black}}
\ctikzset{*-*/.style = {bipole nodes={bcirc}{bcirc}}}
\ctikzset{-*/.style = {bipole nodes={none}{bcirc}}}
\ctikzset{*-/.style = {bipole nodes={bcirc}{none}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[](0,0) to [C,l_=$C$, color=blue, *-*] ++ (0,2);
    \draw[color=blue](2,0) to [C,l_=$C$, *-] ++ (0,2);
    \draw[](4,0) to [C,l_=$C$, color=red, -*] ++ (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good one. The only problem is that I have a big document where I have lots of circuits and I have to change each on by adding b-b. I will try the the solution by Marijn as I don't have to change anything in the document (but currently I have having problems with Marijn's code). Thanks again. I will keep this as my second option.

Comment: You can just redefine `*-*`, `-*`, and `*-`... Although if you want it for all the poles in the circuit Marijn's solution is worth a shot, yes.

Comment: Thanks Rmano. You new solution works for me. Great!

Comment: @Tash thanks! but please check your result --- I am not so confident about color management in `xcircuitikz`. And I should know ;-)...

Comment: It does what I wanted to do so it seems all is ok :)

Answer (score 4):

From page 57 of the manual

[image]

Applying to the capacitor

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,circuits,calc,babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
    % R/.append style={color=red},
    C/.append style={color=blue},
    % battery1/.append style={color=green},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale=1.0,thick]

\draw (0,0)node[circ]{} to [C = $C$] (0,2)node[circ]{};

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a color setting to the code that draws the poles. This is defined in the file `pgfcircbipoles.tex`, in the command `\drawpoles`. Changing this code can be done on the fly using the `xpatch` package, that provides the command `\xpatchcmd` that performs a search and replace action on a command.

In the MWE below the modified command `\drawpoles` uses a new command `\polecolor` for the color, which can be changed within the document. Note that this requires to start a new `\draw` command if the color needs to be changed within a circuit.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\drawpoles}{(\tikztostart) node[\pgf@circ@temp]}{(\tikztostart) node[\pgf@circ@temp,color=\polecolor]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\drawpoles}{(\tikztotarget) node[\pgf@circ@temp]}{(\tikztotarget) node[\pgf@circ@temp,color=\polecolor]}{}{}
\def\polecolor{black}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw(0,0) to [capacitor,l_=$C$,*-*,color=blue](0,2);
  \def\polecolor{green}
  \draw(0,0) -- (2,0) to [capacitor,l_=$C$,*-*,color=blue](2,2) -- (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For older versions of `circuitikz` (before 0.9.1) the patch is as follows:

```
\xpatchcmd{\drawpoles}{(\tikztostart) node[circ]}{(\tikztostart) node[circ,color=\polecolor]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\drawpoles}{(\tikztotarget) node[circ]}{(\tikztotarget) node[circ,color=\polecolor]}{}{}
```

Comment: Hi Marijn, This seems the perfect solution the only problem is that it is not working for me :) . I copied and pasted your code. It told me that I had to install xpatch which I did. After that it runs fine but it gives me blue capacitor with blue ends (poles) which is it default behaviour. Can you tell me why it should happen and what should i do to make it work?

Comment: Hi @Tash, this is probably a version problem (I used an older version), see edit. Does it work for you with this patch?

Comment: In version 0.9.x the code changed a lot, to allow for poles configurability.... The new version should be OK.

Comment: Thanks Marijn. Your solution works now. I will be using Rmano's version as it does not required extra package to be installed :). Thank you both .