# CircuiTikZ How to change a color of a node(dot)

Tags: circuitikz

[image]
\draw (8.5,0) node[above]{$E_1$};
How can I change a color of only one node?If i use *-* it changes my D1 also

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533927/colored-element-with-black-connections-in-circuitikz

Comment: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/g' and I am going to ignore i get this error when i use that

Comment: Which that?  \tikzset will not generate that error, nor is /tikz/g used anywhere.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533927/colored-element-with-black-connections-in-circuitikz Look at this link solution.When I use these commands: \tikzset{bcirc/.style={circ, color=black}}
\ctikzset{b-b/.style = {bipole nodes={bcirc}{bcirc}}}  I get error

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Look, we have seen this exact circuit here several times... Is this a kind of homework? Anyway, if you manage to reduce your example to a simple one and to show the error, I think I can help. But I need that you do a bit of work before!

Comment: I guess you should reference the previous work done in "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543185/drawing-amplifier-circuit-in-circuitikz/543201" by @js bibra.